# how to filter duplicate rows with different value

Tags: sql

I hv a table like this

```
Model     Qty        Date
ABC        1         20110102
ABC       -1         20110105
QWE        1         20110103
ZXC        1         20110103
ABC        1         20110110
QWE       -1         20110110
```

I wish to hv the final output like this:-

```
Model     Qty        Date
ZXC        1         20110103
ABC        1         20110110
```

How can I do this via SQL ?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain the logic that takes you from the original table to the result. We are not mind readers.

Comment: which database are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want the sum of the Qty and the latest Date for each Model:

```
SELECT Model, SUM(Qty), MAX(Date)
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Model
HAVING SUM(Qty) <> 0
```

QWE has a sum of Qty = 0 and therefore should not be returned, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Model, t1.Qty, t1.Date from thetable t1 where t1.Date = (select max(t2.Date) from thetable t2 where t2.Model=t1.Model)
```

Comment: this selects the record with the newest date